# Array list with integers, receiving an error

Tags: java, xml, arraylist

I'm running this on an xml file and when I click on that particular button relating to this code it gives me an error. I think it has something to do with the arraylist combined with integers.

```
    public void doError(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    ArrayList<Integer> integers =null;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        integers.add(i);
    }
```

Comment: "when I click on that particular button relating to this code it gives me an error" - cool, thanks for sharing. Was there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: You need to do: `List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();`

Comment: Use java when you know java. Seems like you need a bit more practicing.

Comment: Why else would I be here? I am new to java so obviously some things will get overlooked. I'm here to learn and get better.

Answer (score 2):

ArrayList is never instantiated.

```
public void doError(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
ArrayList<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    integers.add(i);
}
```

Comment: That seemed to fix the issue. Appreciate your help! :)

Comment: `new ArrayList<>();` you don't need to repeat the type.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize the `ArrayList` like this:

```
   ArrayList<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Because you can't add integer to an `ArrayList` `null`

Comment: I completely overlooked that. Thanks for your help friend

Comment: `new ArrayList<>();` you don't need to repeat the type.